# I can't use AJAX to save information about liked movies

Tags: javascript, json, django, ajax, session

I am new to Django and to creating web applications in general. So I don't really understand what I did wrong. I have a web application with movies.

[my site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4zE6.jpg)

By clicking on the like button, the id of the liked movie should be saved.

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        const likeButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".like-button");

        likeButtons.forEach(button => {
            button.addEventListener("click", function () {
                const movieId = this.getAttribute("data-id");

                if (!this.classList.contains("liked")) {
                    this.classList.add("liked");
                    sendLikeToServer(movieId, true);
                } else {
                    this.classList.remove("liked");
                    sendLikeToServer(movieId, false);
                }
            });
        });

        function sendLikeToServer(movieId, likeStatus) {
            fetch('/like-movie/', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'X-CSRFToken': getCookie('csrftoken')
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ movieId: movieId, like: likeStatus })
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                if (data.likedMovies.length === 3) {
                    window.location.href = "{% url 'recommendations' %}";
                }
            });
        
        }


        function getCookie(name) {
            let cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== "") {
                const cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
                for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === name + "=") {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(
                            cookie.substring(name.length + 1)
                        );
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue;
        }
    });
</script>
```

In views.py the method is prescribed:

```
def like_movie(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    movie_id = data.get('movieId')
    like_status = data.get('like')

    liked_movies = request.session.get('liked_movies', [])

    if like_status and movie_id not in liked_movies:
        liked_movies.append(movie_id)
    elif not like_status and movie_id in liked_movies:
        liked_movies.remove(movie_id)

    request.session['liked_movies'] = liked_movies

    return JsonResponse({'status': 'success', 'liked_movies': liked_movies})
```

In urls.py also provided a URL route:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('filmlibrary/', views.Filmlibrary, name='filmlibrary'),
    path('like-movie/', views.like_movie, name='like_movie'),
    path('recommendations/', views.Recommendations, name='recommendations'),
]
```

So, when I click on the like of a movie, I get an error in the browser console:

[erorr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmYVY.png)

On the one hand, I understand what the second mistake is about. The Response contains the html of the page with the error. On the other hand, I don't understand what to do about it. Please help me with this problem!

I tried adding to urls.py The project has a like-movie route, and the first error disappeared, but this is not what I need. In this case, the address bar says http://127.0.0.1:8000/like-movie/filmlibrary /, but I need to http://127.0.0.1:8000/movies_app/filmlibrary /.

In general, I want to be redirected to the page after liking three movies recommendations.html and there were liked movies and recommendations for them. If anything, I use the Neo4j database and the neomodel library